# I need more help on calculus integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose $\int_{-1}^{4}f(x)dx=6 ,  \int_{-1}^{4}g(x)dx=-3,  \int_{-1}^{0}g(x)dx=-1$

find $\int_{0}^{4}g(x)dx$

Comment: Use dollar signs to enclose mathematics!

Comment: It also isn't a good idea to post similar questions back-to-back-to-back without stating anything about your attempts. It's like you're just seeking answers without even trying yourself.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**: $f(x)$ has nothing to do with this. $$\int_{-1}^4g(x)\,dx=\int_{-1}^0g(x)\,dx+\int_0^4g(x)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $\quad I_1 = \int_{-1}^{4}g(x)\;dx=-3,$

Let $\quad I_2 = \int_{-1}^{0}g(x)\;dx=-1.$

$$\int_{0}^{4}g(x)\;dx = I_1 - I_2 \quad = \quad \int_{-1}^{4}g(x)\;dx \quad - \quad \int_{-1}^{0}g(x)\;dx$$

Comment: The fact that you're given $\int f(x)$ is useless. It's what they call a "red herring"!